# Can I have a header for cell in UITableview instead of header for section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My original problem was my cells stuck to each other without any space among them.

I found a solution by having a section header and make the background clear color. This fixed the space problem but I want to have to sections in my tableView and each section will have x amount of cells.

How can I have a space to separate my cells from each other in each section?

Comment: Why not make the cells taller and leave some space at the top or bottom?

Comment: This sound good. How can I add a space at the to or bottom of the cell. If you have source for me to teach me how to do it I will appreciate that. How ever I will also try to forger it out by myself.
Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove cell's separator from TableView. `table.separatorStyle = .None`. And than leave some space between cell's content and bottom edge.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a View object into the cell.
2. Put all your objects into the View.
3. Add top and bottom constraint to the View.